# Changing an html image by a javascript function call

Tags: javascript, html

My web page has an "upload image" placeholder image by default. I want the user to be able to upload an image and have a javascript function call change the image "images/upload_wText.png" in the code below to whatever image file they chose. I've seen several similar questions (and answers) on SO but they don't exactly address what I'm trying to accomplish. I have tried tweaking the some of the solutions but nothing has worked. This is for a school programming assignment and we are not allowed to use jQuery. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="uploadImgContainer" id="uploadImgCont">
    <img src="images/upload_wText.png" alt="upload button"/>
</div>
<div class="uploadButtonContainer">
    <input type = "file" id="uploadImageBtn" onchange="uploadPetImg(this);"/>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
function uploadPetImg(myImagePath) {
    document.getElementById("uploadImgCont").src = myImagePath;
}
```

Comment: Post your javascript code.

Comment: I saw that another user trying to do something similar and they passed in "this" to the function. I thought it would be a file path but it doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Refer this:  [preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two error
First, you try to set src to a <**div**> element. 
Second, the way you try to get selected image file.

So, move id **uploadImgCont** to <**img**> tag and remove change attrib from <**input**> element.

```
<div class="uploadImgContainer">
   <img src="images/upload_wText.png" id="uploadImgCont" alt="Image"/>
</div>
<div class="uploadButtonContainer">
   <input type = "file" id="uploadImageBtn"/>
</div>
```

just add input listener within js like this, using only pure javascript

```
function uploadPetImg(imagePath){
   document.getElementById('uploadImgCont').src=imagePath;
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('uploadImageBtn').addEventListener('change',function(event){
    var imagePath=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    uploadPetImg(imagePath);
});
}
```

[Here's the fiddle(link)](https://jsfiddle.net/KheinHtoo/4kLLo1rq/46/)

Hope this help.